# Regular expression to match a URL

Tags: regular-expressions, hyperlinks

I am trying to construct a regexp for URLs (for grabbing them out quickly out of a paragraph, region, etc.). I don't need it advanced, but I am having some troubles with it. Here is my attempt, which doesn't work too well:

```
(re-search-forward (rx (minimal-match (and "http" (*? anything) (or ")" "\"" "[:blank:]")))))
```

This other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) has some url regexps, but those aren't for emacs.

P.S. I also don't understand how `match-beginning` works as its description is a little bit mystic.

Comment: `gnus-art.el` defines `gnus-button-url-regexp`, `rcirc.el` defines `rcirc-url-regexp`, `erc-button.el` defines `erc-button-url-regexp`, `ffap.el` defines `ffap-url-regexp`, `goto-addr.el` defines `goto-address-url-regexp`, and that's just some of the built-in ones, so I recommend you reuse one of them. See also `thingatpt.el`. For `match-beginning`, see [`(eintr) fwd-para while`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/fwd_002dpara-while.html), and [`(elisp) Match Data`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Match-Data.html) along with its subnodes.

Comment: "I am having some troubles with it. Here is my attempt, which doesn't work too well" -- you should explain what "troubles" and "doesn't work" actually means, rather than expecting people to guess.

Comment: @Basil AFAICS those find just the beginning of a URL. So, if a link is inside parentheses, the parenthesis will be grabbed. That's what I tried to avoid in my regexp, but it is too greedy (try `https://site.com ) "`, it stops at the second space)

Comment: @phils sure, see my comment above

Comment: @user3496846 Some Emacs variables only match the beginning, yes, but `rcirc-url-regexp` for one matches the entire URL. You can also piece together the parts you're interested in if you look at `thingatpt.el`.

Comment: n.b. `(rx "[:blank:]")` matches the literal string `[:blank:]`, not the character class.  That's how double-quoted strings work in rx (i.e. like using `regexp-quote`).  You wanted to use the symbol `blank` there.

Comment: @Basil Awesome! `rcirc-url-regexp` works (for those who read this in the future: don't forget to `M-x rcirc` so that it's loaded). You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @phils Now, that makes sense. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Please move the info from all relevant comments to the question or to answers. Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions should stand alone.